# Pagination and mod rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

The modrewrite below works when i have this which is exactly how i want: "www.mysite.com/files/person/john.html"
files.php?q=person

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /$1.php?q=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /files.php?q=$1 [L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .txt .php
```

The problem I have is when i have pagination and i have more than one person to display like this: "www.mysite.com/person/2" this becomes person.php, however there is no person.php and the modrewrite should only look at this condition below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /files.php?q=$1 [L]
```

The thing is this "www.mysite.com/person/2" works when i only have this modrewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /$1.php?q=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /files.php?q=$1 [L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .txt .php
```

however, the minute i uncomment it, it stops working? what to do, any ideas?

Comment: what do you need exactly? do you have person.php or not? you explained very complicated.

Comment: I don't have person.php; basically when i have a pagination, i want the mod rewrite to go to files.php. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regex for this.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z]+)(.html)?$ /$1.php?q=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /files.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /files.php?q=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

explanation for regex

```
()       : means group and match that
[a-zA-Z] : means only letters lower or upper
.html    : means match ".html"
?        : means 0 or more times
[0-9]    : means only numbers 0 to 9
+        : means at least 1 or more times
```

Comment: the problem with this is when i only have this www.mysite.com/person my site breaks. as the above doesn't work.

Comment: i gave all codes, first i gave was just part of it, try that one and tell me if something is wrong

Comment: very close, when i have a link like this: www.mysite.com/person/2, the rewrite becomes this: files.php?q=2 rather it should be files.php?q=person; in my php code i actually try to extract "2" from the "/person/2". so this get called: files.php?q=person, then i grab the last 2 from the link here:www.mysite.com/person/2 for the pagination.

Comment: check the code again, with this code, you can get page like `$_GET['p']` and `$_GET['q']` will be `person`

Comment: ok will check it again. thanks for your help, your help is the closest to the solution. i will test it out and let you know.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z]+) /$1.php?q=$2 [L]this is working: i changed the rewrite rule to this: